# Crossdomain WCF - Silverlight configuration error a:ActionNotSupported

Tags: silverlight, wcf, web-config, cross-domain, wcf-configuration

I tried to run WCF functions from SilverLight Code. WCF is runing on site www.my-site.com
Silverlight application is downloaded from site www.my-site.com as < IFrame/> part of html page which is downloaded from site www.vkontakte.ru. I have received an **a:ActionNotSupported** error.
What is wrong?

Here is request that was sent by my silverlight application:

POST http://www.my-site.com/MyService.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.my-site.com/ClientBin/MySlApp.xap
Accept-Language: ru-RU
Content-Length: 153
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IMyService/Add"
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Host: www.my-site.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <a1>1</a1>
      <a2>1</a2>
    </Add>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

As result I have recieved folowing response:

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 710
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 11 Sep 2011 16:34:19 GMT

```
<Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
  <Code>
    <Value>Sender</Value>
    <Subcode>
      <Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">
        a:ActionNotSupported
      </Value>
    </Subcode>
  </Code>
  <Reason>
    <Text xml:lang="en-US">
      The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver,
      due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.
      This may be because of either a contract mismatch
      (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver)
      or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.
      Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding
      (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
    </Text>
  </Reason>
</Fault>
```

Silverlight request code:

```
        BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress =
            new EndpointAddress("http://www.my-site.com/MyService.svc");
        IDbService service =
            new ChannelFactory<IDbService>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress)
                .CreateChannel();
        AsyncCallback asy = delegate(IAsyncResult result)
                                {
                                    Trace.WriteLine(service.EndAdd(result));
                                };
        service.BeginAdd(1, 1, asy, null);
```

Silverlight operation contract interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginAdd(long a1, long a2, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

    long EndAdd(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

WCF operation contract interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    long Add(long a1, long a2);
}
```

WCF Service code:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(
    RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public long Add(long a1, long a2)
    {
        return a1 + a2;
    }
}
```

part of web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MySlApp.Web.ServiceMyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MySlApp.Web.MyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <enableWebScript />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="MySlApp.Web.DbService"
             behaviorConfiguration="MySlApp.Web.ServiceMyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <endpoint address=""
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MySlApp.Web.IMyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

clientaccesspolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
        <domain uri="http://www.my-site.com" />
        <domain uri="http://www.vkontakte.ru" />
        <domain uri="http://*.vkontakte.ru" />
        <domain uri="http://www.vk.com" />
        <domain uri="http://*.vk.com" />
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="www.my-site.com" />
  <allow-access-from domain="www.vkontakte.ru" />
  <allow-access-from domain="*.vkontakte.ru" />
  <allow-access-from domain="www.vk.com" />
  <allow-access-from domain="*.vk.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Did you create it as a Silverlight compatible WCF service or plain old WCF service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a cross-domain problem. The issue is that you're sending a request which conforms to the `basicHttpBinding`, while the server endpoint uses the `webHttpBinding`. If you change the web.config to the one listed below, it should work.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MySlApp.Web.ServiceMyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="MySlApp.Web.DbService"
             behaviorConfiguration="MySlApp.Web.ServiceMyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MySlApp.Web.IMyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you can't change your service, then you'll need to change the client. `webHttpBinding` endpoints also known as WCF WebHttp endpoints, or (somehow overusing the 'REST' term) WCF REST endpoints, can't be accessed directly via SL using the WCF programming model (client class, `ChannelFactory<T>`, etc). It can be done (see the post about [consuming REST/POX services via SL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/04/29/consuming-rest-pox-services-in-silverlight-4.aspx), and the post about [consuming REST/JSON services via SL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2010/04/29/consuming-rest-json-services-in-silverlight-4.aspx)), but it's not something too easy (most people use simple classes such as `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` to consume those services.